# MySQL - Two records set from one query with different Order and Limit

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I don't know if what I want to do is possible, but let me expose my issue.
I have one query like this :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions,
    SUM(report.revenue) AS revenue,
    report.country AS country
FROM
    report_table report
WHERE
    date >= '2014-01-01'
        AND date <= '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY report.country
ORDER BY revenue DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

This query gives me the 5 records with the highest revenue. I would also like to have the 5 records with the highest impressions count. This is the result of this query :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions,
    SUM(report.revenue) AS revenue,
    report.country AS country
FROM
    report_table report
WHERE
    date >= '2014-01-01'
        AND date <= '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY report.country
ORDER BY impressions DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

My issue is that I don't want to execute the same query twice because the SUM would have to be recalculated again. 
Is there a way to get the revenue top 5 and the impressions top 5 without having to do the sum twice ? (I don't need to get the same record twice). Or what would be the best way to do this to get the highest performances ? (Because I could just do a UNION of my two requests but that would not seem to be the most optimized)

ANSWER : 
Here is a working solution for my problem :

```
    SELECT impressions, 
    revenue, 
    country,
    @rn := if (@n = n,@rn + 1,1) AS seqnum,
    @n := n AS dn 
    FROM (
    SELECT SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions, 
            SUM(report.revenue) AS revenue, 
            report.country AS country, 
            n 
        FROM country_report report 
        cross join (select 1 as n union all select 2) n 
        cross join (select @rn := 0, @n := 1) m 
        WHERE date >= "2014-01-01" AND date <= "2014-01-31" 
        GROUP BY n,report.country 
        ORDER BY n,(case when n = 1 then revenue else impressions end) DESC 
    ) r 
    WHERE if (@n = n,@rn + 1,1) <=5
```

Comment: Do you need the bigest five impressions and also their revenue as well?

Comment: I need the bigest 5 impressions, and the bigest 5 revenue. I don't need to get the revenue for the 5 bigest impressions. (If I understand the question correctly)

Comment: Seems like a good case for a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) using [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html).

Comment: Marcus : Yes I have thought about the temporary table. Do you think the temporary table offers best performance compared to the solution I have added in my question ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that you can get the full list, sorted first by revenue and then impressions

```
SELECT SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions, SUM(report.revenue) AS revenue,
       report.country AS country
FROM report_table report cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
WHERE date >= "2014-01-01" AND date <= "2014-01-31"
GROUP BY n, report.country
ORDER BY (case when n = 1 then revenue else impressions end) DESC;
```

Now the problem is to get the first five values from each group.  You can do this using a subquery:

```
select impressions, revenue, country
from (SELECT SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions, SUM(report.revenue) AS revenue,
             report.country AS country,
             @rn := if (@n = n then @rn + 1 else 1 end) as seqnum,
             @n := n
      FROM report_table report cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2) n cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @n := -1)
      WHERE date >= "2014-01-01" AND date <= "2014-01-31"
      GROUP BY n.n, report.country
      ORDER BY n.n, (case when n.n = 1 then revenue else impressions end) DESC
     ) r
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working very well ! I had to change a few things to make the second request work. I'll update my first post for future reference :)

Comment: When I just looked at the query again, I realized that I left out the assignment of `@n` in the `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can have the bigest five impressions and revenue in this way too. This will calculate exacltly as many times as you query.

```
(SELECT 
        SUM(report.impressions) AS impressions,
        report.country AS country
    FROM
        report_table report
    WHERE
        date >= '2014-01-01'
            AND date <= '2014-01-31'
    GROUP BY report.country
    ORDER BY impressions DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5)
    Union
    (SELECT 
        SUM(report.revenue),
        report.country
    FROM
        report_table report
    WHERE
        date >= '2014-01-01'
            AND date <= '2014-01-31'
    GROUP BY report.country
    ORDER BY revenue DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5)
```